# Set 2 button aligment in the middle android

Tags: android, button, layout

I have a double question:

1. I want to set two buttons, Aligned in the middle of the screen and equispaced of the center. How I can do it?
2. I want to do the same but now I need 4 buttons: 2 upside and 2 downside.

Edit:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/selTemplate_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_noteText"
    android:text="@string/select_template"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />


<Button
     android:id="@+id/saveText_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/save_text"
     android:layout_below="@+id/text_noteText"
     android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/viewTemplate_button"/>
```

My two button are in a scrollview so I can´t create various linearlayout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tihrs.jpg this is my layout.

Comment: Share what you do/try so far

Comment: put your xml file here

Comment: share some thoughts/code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for Question 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Solution for Question 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to use multiple layouts? Simply use Linearlayout as Parent and make

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

All the views will be centre

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RelativeLayout` .

1. Two buttons in center.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"     
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginStart="50dp"/>

    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Four buttons in center.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Output of First question https://i.stack.imgur.com/34QJ7.png

1.For your first question follow the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btn_1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn_2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output of second question https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5CBS.png

2.For your second question follow the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btn_1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn_2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn_3"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn_4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```